# Loading settings.py config file into a dict

Tags: python, configuration, configuration-files

Say I have a file called settings.py and it's content is the following:

```
{
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": True,
    "word_wrap": "true",
    "font_face": "Monaco",
    "font_size": 14.0,
    "highlight_line": True,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        ""
    ],
    "what": '''
            This is python file, not json
            '''
}
```

How can I get it into a dict called settings in my main app file app.py?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use JSON? Python has a `json` module that makes it incredibly easy to decode JSON data. It also avoids the nasty side effects of loading unverified python code that has been mentioned in the comments of some of the answers.

Comment: @Michael Because I want to use ''' ... '''

Comment: Can you add an example to the question?

Comment: In tripple quoted string I won't need to escape anything if I use Python, I'll have a mess with json if I want to write the setting file by hand with a lot of " and ' in string literal. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In that case maybe you want to write your settings file as a `INI` file and load it using [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/configparser.html). IMHO `INI` files are more human-readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to do this safely.

```
import ast

data="""\
{
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": True,
    "word_wrap": "true",
    "font_face": "Monaco",
    "font_size": 14.0,
    "highlight_line": True,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        ""
    ],
    "what": '''
            This is python file, not json
            '''
}\
"""

print(ast.literal_eval(data))
```

Giving us:

```
{'what': '\n            This is python file, not json\n            ', 'font_size': 14.0, 'translate_tabs_to_spaces': True, 'font_face': 'Monaco', 'word_wrap': 'true', 'highlight_line': True, 'ignored_packages': ['']}
```

## <s>Edit:</s>

<s>Given the new comment from the asker that suggests that he wants to be able to use `...` in his config, `ast.literal_eval()` will **not** be suitable, as it can't handle ellipses. It's not quite clear if this is what he meant, and this is still a good answer to the question that was asked.</s>

Turns out the asker was talking about triple quoted strings, which are handled by this correctly.

Comment: -1 No need of literal eval, just import the module and get all python freebies

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. The name of the file is `settings.py`. It's a python file, and it sounds like it's part of a package written by the author. This isn't random untrusted text from an unknown user.

Comment: The aim is for settings to be changed - and it's Python syntax, so it makes sense for it to still be `.py`. Why introduce an (unneeded) risk of an attack vector - however unlikely, and force the wanted layout of the file to change, when there is a good, easy solution that does neither?

Comment: I'm sorry, by that paranoid logic we should be using `ast` to do all imports that it can handle instead of importing directly. That doesn't make _any sense_ to me. If someone has access to `settings.py` then they also have access to the rest of the source. They can do whatever they want; `ast.literal_eval` won't keep them out at that point.

Comment: @senderle I'm not saying that we should use it for all imports - just it makes perfect sense for settings files. You don't want to let the settings file execute arbitrary code, so why let it? As I say, what about a user copying and pasting some config off a site. A settings file is not something a user would consider as being a potential attack vector, so they are unlikely to check it. I'm not saying it's likely, but I really don't see a reason not to use `literal_eval()` here when it has two advantages.

Comment: @Lattyware I agree with senderie that if an attacker can compromise your settings file then your whole source code base is also compromised.

Comment: @cobie That is untrue - the reality is it's a lot more likely that a user will update a settings file than any source code. A lot of people follow guides and fixes from the internet that involve changing settings files.

Comment: @Lattyware so you are assuming that those fixes users implement can be malicious?

Comment: @cobie If you import a settings file, yes, they potentially could be.

Comment: @cobie So you are saying it's a better idea to use a method that requires a different setup for the file (assigning the dict to a name), and allows arbitrary code execution, than using this simple alternative? Even if you think that allowing code to be executed in the settings file isn't a problem, this method still has the edge.

Comment: I accepted this solution because it's the cleanest option for the setting file itself (no variable assignment)

Comment: Although I still think this isn't _necessary_, I take your point that it doesn't have a clear downside in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Why not name that dict say `settings` and than just import it from settings.py e.g.

**settings.py**

```
settings = {} # fill with your data
```

use it like this

```
>>> from settings import settings
>>> print settings
{}
```

Alternate solutions is to just add variables at settings module level and use them directly, why you need a dict? e.g.

**settings.py**

```
translate_tabs_to_spaces = True
# more settings
```

use it like this

```
>>> import settings
>>> settings.translate_tabs_to_spaces
True
```

Comment: -1, This is dangerous - it could contain malicious code. It also requires changing the data file.

Comment: @Lattyware really, OP hasn't told the how settings.py is created, may be it is just a settings file as used in django

Comment: @Lattyware i don't really see anything dangerous in this approach. if the dict is not named its less dangerous? to me this is the right way to do it. who makes a file with a dict in there without naming it to a variable?

Comment: @aschmid00 The problem is you can put any code into this file and it will be run if you import it. And as to a who puts a dict into a file without naming it, well, someone writing a settings file. Most settings files don't begin with `settings = { ...`.

Comment: @Lattyware I think your suggestion of not using a proper module is wrong and my suggestion is not dangerous at all, if users are submitting settings files online to be run, it may be dangerous but if this is just a settings files included with code than it is not at all dangerous, using python module as settings file have many advantages like you can have `if/else`, loops etc

Comment: @AnuragUniyal The asker didn't want those things. The `literal_eval()` solution is the one that best fits what the asker wanted. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Lattyware so you agree that solution is not dangerous as you mentioned earlier, but you think you solution is simpler?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal Don't try and twist my words - I think that it's a simpler solution, and I feel your solution is *potentially* dangerous.

Comment: dangerous we can't tell unless OP tells who creates settings.py and how it is used, but it looks like a normal module and it is should be ok, simpler? is `import settings` simpler or `import ast; settings = ast.literal_eval( open('settings.py').read())` simpler

Answer (score 1):

Give the settings dict a name in the settings module then import the settings module into your module and load it into a variable like

```
import settings
your_settings = settings.settings_dict
```

Comment: -1, This is dangerous - it could contain malicious code. It also requires changing the data file.

Comment: if you are using a settings module then it most definitely is written by you I would guess

Comment: @Lattyware really, OP hasn't told the how settings.py is created, may be it is just a settings file as used in django

Comment: I'm not saying it's likely, but why introduce that risk? If a user blindly copy/pastes a settings file, why let them potentially introduce something malicious.

Comment: @Lattyware so in your opinion django project should not use settings.py ?

Comment: @Lattyware you could make the same argument for a user copying and pasting code from the internet.

Comment: @cobie Yes. You could. In this case, the settings file can happily be parsed by `literal_eval()` in it's current form - so why bother changing the file and making the file able to execute arbitrary code when that isn't the aim?